# BigInteger Log Issue on large numbers

Tags: c#, .net, math, biginteger, logarithm

The code below takes a BigInteger `n` and finds a number less than `n` that is also a `power of 2`. It works fine with small numbers but the first branch of the `if` statement does not work for int.MaxValue and above. Apparently subtracting `1` (`BigInteger.Log(n - 1)`) is not enough for larger numbers.

How can I calculate a number to subtract that is large enough to make a difference and yet work on smaller numbers too?

```
public BigInteger FindNearestPowerOfTwo (BigInteger n)
{
    double number = 0;
    BigInteger big = 0;

    if (n.IsPowerOfTwo)
    {
        number = BigInteger.Log(n - 1) / BigInteger.Log(2);
    }
    else
    {
        number = BigInteger.Log(n) / BigInteger.Log(2);
    }

    number = Math.Floor(number);

    big = BigInteger.Pow(2, (int) number);

    return (big);
}
```

Comment: Just curious: what do you do with that?

Comment: To traverse decreasing powers of 2 for an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` branch, you can subtract something from the quotient,

```
number = BigInteger.Log(n)/BigInteger.Log(2) - 0.9;
```

for example (I'd be careful with subtracting 1.0 there since `BigInteger.Log(x)` isn't exact, the quotient could be a little too small, then subtracting 1.0 would give you the wrong power of 2). That works also for pretty large numbers (but a `double` has only 53 bits of precision, so for numbers larger than 2^(2^54) that is guaranteed to fail - however, that's a lot more memory than currently available).

But easier would of course be

```
if (n.IsPowerOfTwo) {
    return n/2;
}
```

However, the `else` branch is problematic. If `n` is very close to a power of 2,

```
BigInteger.Log(n) / BigInteger.Log(2)
```

can be a little too large or too small, moving the quotient across the closest integer to the exact result. You should check that `big` is indeed smaller than `n` and if not, divide by 2.

It may be that [`BigInteger.Log(n, 2.0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268364.aspx) produces more exact results than dividing two natural logarithms. (I don't know the implementation.)

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming that subtracting 0.9 would have a negative impact on small numbers right? I tried multiplying by 0.99D which seems to work so far. Also, I did not understand your last point about the else branch. Could you elaborate please.

Comment: No, subtracting 0.9 is fine for small numbers (as long as they're > 1, but for `n <= 1`, you're having a problem anyway). I subtract it from the quotient, that is the base-2 logarithm. So if `n = 2^k`, `Log(n)/Log(2) = k + floating-point-error`. Subtracting 0.9 safely yields a number strictly between `k-1` and `k` for all reasonable input. Then the cast to `int` makes sure the result is `2^(k-1)`. In the else branch, if `n = 2^k + 1` or `n = 2^k - 1`, `Log(n)/Log(2)` can, for large enough `k`, come out slightly smaller than `k` in the first case, or slightly large in the second due to ...

Comment: floating-point limitations. If that happens (rare, but possible), you'd get a wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ToByteArray` to get an explicit representation, then clear all bits but the highest one.

```
public BigInteger FindNearestPowerOfTwo (BigInteger n) {
    Byte[] a = n.ToByteArray();
    int len = a.Length;
    if (a[len - 1] == 0) len--; // leading zero to maintain sign
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) a[i] = 0;
    int x = a[len - 1] & 255;
    int y = 1;
    while (x > 1) {
      x >>= 1;
      y <<= 1;
    }
    a[len - 1] = y;
    return new BigInteger(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or the lazy man's version:

```
public static BigInteger FindNearestPowerOfTwo(BigInteger number) {
    bool isPower = number.IsPowerOfTwo;
    int count = 0;
    while(!number.IsZero) {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        number = number >> 1;
        count ++ ;
    }
    return BigInteger.Pow(2, count - (isPower ? 2: 1));
}
```